# How to reuse code in Puppeteer's pageFunction?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

the code i want to be able to execute:

```
const checkVisible = async (element: HTMLElement): Promise<boolean> => {
  const style = window.getComputedStyle(element)
  return style && style.visibility !== 'hidden' && hasVisibleBoundingBox()

  function hasVisibleBoundingBox(): boolean {
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect()
    return !!(rect.top || rect.bottom || rect.width || rect.height)
  }
}

...
await page.waitForFunction((el) => checkVisible(el), { timeout }, element1)
...
await page.waitForFunction((el) => {
  // some more complex usage
  if (!checkVisible(el)) return false
  ...
}, { timeout }, element2)
```

checkVisible function created in the node cannot be executed in pageFunction, even though it is fully adapted to the browser environment.

If I define window.checkVisible with page.evaluate() as early as possible. then it's difficult to cope with the challenge of frequent and erratic page refresh/redirect.

```
page.evaluate(() => {
  window.checkVisible = async (element: HTMLElement): Promise<boolean> => {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(element)
    return style && style.visibility !== 'hidden' && hasVisibleBoundingBox()

    function hasVisibleBoundingBox(): boolean {
      const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect()
      return !!(rect.top || rect.bottom || rect.width || rect.height)
    }
  }
})
```

But I'm more reluctant to write the checkVisible() code countless times. is there any help?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. After you've attached it to window one time, just call `page.evaluate(() => checkVisible(document.querySelector(whatever)))`, right?

Comment: @ggorlen Before any execution of page.waitForFunction(), the webpage may be refreshed for many other reasons and window.checkVisible has been lost.

Comment: I just want to simply reuse pageFunction's code, attached it to window will bring a lot of uncertainty.

Comment: What sort of uncertainty are you worried about? If you're concerned about name clashes, namespace it in a unique object like libraries did before modules and bundlers. If you want it to be easy to call but don't want to attach it to the window, write your own helper in Node, `const checkVisible = page => page.evaluate(/* the code */)`, then it's simply `await checkVisible(page)` whenever you need the logic to run. Either way, you needn't write it over and over.

Comment: @ggorlen checkVisible() must be executed in the context of pageFunction , like this:  
```js  
await page.waitForFunction((el) => {
   // some more complex usage
   if (!checkVisible(el)) return false
   ...
}, { timeout }, element2)
```
So you can't create helper in node.

Comment: The so-called uncertainty, your page not only runs these puppeteers scripts you wrote, also a lot of other js code is running. Simple example: Check the inventory after the product page is loaded, you have defined window.checkVisible at this time. If there is an abnormal result in checking the inventory, the page will be refreshed once, so that your pre-defined window.checkVisible is lost.